# Convert TXT file to CSV using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have the `txt` output, which I am willing to convert into `CSV`

```
Output(data.txt)


apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,18452          
apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,0
```

OR

```
name_of_bucket:apache_web,bucket_id:/mystorage/nfs/indexes,size:18452
name_of_bucket:apache_web,bucket_id:/mystorage/nfs/indexes,size:0
```

Expecting

```
name_of_bucket,bucket_id,size    
apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,18452   
apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert txt to csv python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642082/convert-txt-to-csv-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")

String = ""
for line in file:
    String += line

file.close()

file = open("data.csv", "a")
file.write(String)
file.close()
```

Comment: I am getting the output as is in the txt, it's not converting to CSV which I am expecting in the question

Answer (score 0):

A .csv file is a plaintext format that is interpreted by Excel into cells, so you can just write that output into a ".csv" file extension like so:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

with open("data.csv", "w+") as csvfile:
    csvfile.write("name_of_bucket,bucket_id,size\n")
    csvfile.writelines(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you had a input file called `data.txt` that contained the following four lines, namely in both of your possible formats:

```
apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,18452
apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,0
name_of_bucket:apache_web,bucket_id:/mystorage/nfs/indexes,size:18452
name_of_bucket:apache_web,bucket_id:/mystorage/nfs/indexes,size:0
```

The following script can read each line, and remove the prefixes from each column and write the amended values back to an `output.csv` file:

```
import csv

header = ['name_of_bucket', 'bucket_id', 'size']

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f_data, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f_data)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for row in csv_data:
        row = [cell.replace(r + ':', '') for cell, r in zip(row, header)]
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving you an `output.csv` file containing:

```
name_of_bucket,bucket_id,size
apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,18452
apache_web,/my_storage/nfs/indexes,0
apache_web,/mystorage/nfs/indexes,18452
apache_web,/mystorage/nfs/indexes,0
```

Firstly it makes use of Python `csv` library to automatically split entries in each row and make a list of values. Next it uses a list comprehension to remove the corresponding header value (with `:` appended) if present. Next it writes the modified list of entries to a new output file.

`zip()` is used to allow you to read one value at a time from multiple lists, in this case it takes one entry from the row (`cell`), and the corresponding header value (`r`) which it uses to do a string `replace()` to replace the text with an empty string, i.e. delete it if present.

Tested using Python 2.7.12