# How to write elements from a list into a csv with different columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a list for example

```
['1 sam 2000','2 jack 1232','3 lily 34']
```

Each element in the list actually contains information for 3 columns and separated by spaces.
These were read from a `txt` file.
Now I wish to save these data into a `csv` file.

I read them using

```
with open('test.txt','r',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as file:
    li = []
    for i in file:

        i =i.rstrip('\n')
        li.append(i)
```

Or shall can I simply convert txt into csv ?

Comment: Your title says you are trying to write to a file. Your question looks like you are trying to read from the file. It's not really clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a space-separated CSV file (awkward wording, I know) into a list. Just use the `csv` module.

```
import csv

with open('test.txt','r',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore', newline='') as file:
    li = list(csv.reader(file, sep=' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## assumed data to format in the list format
## split each element in the list and create another list of list item
data=['1 sam 2000','2 jack 1232','3 lily 34']

## to save the final result initialize the variable
final_data=[]

## go though each element in the list
for i in data:
    # split each element with the space
    subdata=i.split(" ")
    ## add the element to the final_data
    final_data.append(subdata)


## import pandas and convert list into pandas dataframe
## convert pandas dataframe to csv using to_csv method in pandas
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(final_data).to_csv("result.csv")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Learn proper formatting before posting is challenge for me. I have posted with few python commets but later accepting auto format suggestion only the above code left.

Comment: Any video link to see how to post the code with proper format?

Answer (score 1):

For every element of the list, you could use a `split(" ")` to create a separate list and feed into the csv library:

```
import csv

data= ['1 sam 2000','2 jack 1232','3 lily 34']

with open("csv_file.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for element in data:
        writer.writerow(element.split(" "))
```

This should create a file called csv_file.csv with:

```
1,sam,2000
2,jack,1232
3,lily,34
```

If you need to add the headers, you can do it adding this line before the for loop:

`writer.writerow((header1, header2, header3...))`

Answer (score 1):

you could skip the list step an go from a txt file directly to csv if you want,
this would do the job:

```py
import csv
    
with open('yourtextfile.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('result.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('title', 'intro'))
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

i used this answer as example:
[Convert txt to csv python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642082/convert-txt-to-csv-python-script)