# Convert .txt to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zkLk_g2n_ViENyxA1e_pUBa2jfdt91BRt0Eob1csxGI/edit)I have text such that:

```
Roll no.   Name     S1     S2    S3     S4     S5

123       Subh      301   302   303     304   305

                    20     21   22      23     23

124      Sagar     306    200   207     205    201

                   30      32    43      81     22
```

I want convert these in csv file such that:

```
Roll no.,   Name,    S1,     S2,    S3,     S4,     S5,


123,       Subh,     [301   [302   [303     [304   [305

                     20],   21],  22],     23],     23],

124,      Sagar,     [306,   [200 ,  [207 ,    [205,    [201,

                     30],      32],    43],     81],     22],
```

I try all things but can't able to find solution can someone help me to solve this problem.

I also add docs for refrence.

Comment: Do you want a comma after EVERY field?  You can do that in a text editor pretty easily.

Comment: Are the value two rows or 4 rows? is the first row first value 301 or 30120?

Comment: i wnat  2 rows in csv but there is 4 rows in text file and let me edit my question.

Comment: but there is so many rows @TimRoberts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert txt to csv python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642082/convert-txt-to-csv-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get your expected output.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("new_created.txt", sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df.iloc[1::2] = df.iloc[1::2].shift(2, axis=1)
df.ffill(inplace=True)
out = df.groupby(["Roll No.", "Marks"], as_index=False).agg(list)
```

Then, if you need to make a (`.csv`), use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) :

```
out.to_csv("output_file.csv", sep="\t", index=False) #tab-delimited csv
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out.head().to_string())

    Roll No.             Marks         S1         S2         S3         S4          S5          S6
0  160200006  Christine Nelson  [301, 28]  [124, 30]  [027, 24]  [028, 23]  [29.0, 22]  [48.0, 19]
1  160200008   Kelsey Thompson  [301, 19]  [302, 13]  [027, 12]  [028, 12]  [29.0, 13]  [48.0, 19]
2  160200013       Wendy Yoder  [301, 23]  [302, 25]  [802, 19]  [803, 18]  [41.0, 17]  [48.0, 16]
3  160200016     Karen Fleming  [301, 26]  [124, 20]  [809, 16]  [834, 22]  [29.0, 14]  [48.0, 23]
4  160200021     Dillon Miller  [301, 26]  [124, 29]  [027, 12]  [028, 14]  [29.0, 19]  [48.0, 23]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use python regex to seperate each column and row from other.
You can learn Python Regex [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

Another solution is using CSV file handler using CSV library. To know more about it with its documentation click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

And finally if all above couldn't solve your problem you can use `numpy.loadtext()`methode to convert it into array(s).