# Extract data from file.txt text file to csv

Tags: python, csv, txt

I have this .txt file and i would like to convert it to .csv in Python, could you help me?

[File.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IsCY.jpg)

I need to extract the txt data to csv file in this format:

|Case code| Site of injury| If is not fatal,day away from home| Gender | Nationality |...........

| 239            | Head             |1                                                         | M              | ITALY              |...........

And so on for every tag before " : " .
This is the result i'm trying to achieve: [Final results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c9kE.jpg)

Please let me know how can i solve this problem. I'm a beginner in programming and I don't know where to start. Thank you.

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, data or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.   Spending some time with [the Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples may give you ideas how you solve your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert txt to csv python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642082/convert-txt-to-csv-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition with [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.tranpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

(
    pd.read_fwf("input.txt")
        .squeeze()
        .loc[lambda x: x.str.contains(":", na=False)]
        .str.split(":", expand=True)
        .set_index(0)
        .transpose()
        .to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
)
```

##### # Output :

*First nine columns :*

```
0 Case code Site of injury Type of injury day away from home Gender Nationality Type of work contract          Job Seniority of job
1       239           Head       Fracture                  1      M       ITALY    Permanent employee   Other jobs     over 3 years
```

*Shape of the output* : `(1 row, 17 columns)`